# How to track iOS freezings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, performance-testing

I'm looking for ways to get all my iOS app freezes, my intention is to capture it when bench testing isn't enough, for say, when apps must to operate for long periods of time with no interruption and remote monitoring is the only solution.

Are there any ways to combine (processor x memory x storage) loads in a way that we can absolutely tell something wrong is happening ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: It is quite a vague general question, but I understand your frustration - have you tried to use any of the Instruments apple provides along with Xcode? 

Product > Profile (or ⌘I)